# What is the difference between 变 and 变得?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between 变 and 变得?
Is 变得 a word in its own right, or is 得 some sort of complement word?
For example, 眼睛变得亮晶晶。

Answer (score 3):

得 is some sort of complement word here. It tends to be some sort of comment or description of the action in the verb.

The basic structure is:

```
[verb] 得 [description]
```

From your example

> 眼睛变得亮晶晶

变 is verb, 亮晶晶 is description of the eye.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a result complement or state complement? If it is a result complement, does it need 得? If it is a degree complement, doesn't it need 很 as well? Is there another type of complement it could be?

Comment: Is it the same as words such as 长得 and 觉得？

Comment: Is it a complement of state?

Comment: 长得,得 here use to describe the verb, same like the example I shown above.  觉得 is a word, you can't separate them, because  觉 has not meaning.  觉得 mean feel in English.